Type for class properties that extends abstract class definition
Please consider example below
export abstract class Definition {
    [x: string]: string;
}

class A {
    propA = 'A';
    propB = 'B';
}

type AClassKey = keyof A;
const keyOfAClass: AClassKey = 'thisIsNotValidKey';

class B extends Definition {
    propA = 'A';
    propB = 'B';
}

type BClassKey = keyof B;

//This accepts any key because B extends Definition. How to make this accept only defined keys of B class (propA, propB)?
const keyOfBClass: BClassKey = 'thisIsValidKey';

// However if I map at least I get suggestion for defined keys (propA, propB)
type BClassMap =  {[K in keyof B]: unknown}
const bMap:BClassMap = {propA: 'suggestedByAutoComplete', propB: 'suggestedByAutoComplete', someOther: 'notSuggestedButValid'};

Link to example
Is it possible make type BClassKey only accept properties that defined in class B when it extends abstract Definition class?

This feels like a misuse of classes. Where object literals and a object generator function would serve better.  And have better type safety.  The abstract Definition is so vague as to be useless.

You could use some utility type to omit the string index:
export abstract class Definition {
    [x: string]: string;
}

type OmitIndex<T> = keyof { [K in keyof T as string extends K ? never: K]: never }

class B extends Definition{
    propA = 'A';
    propB = 'B';
}

type BClassKey = OmitIndex<B>;

const keyOfBClass: BClassKey = 'NOT VALID';

Playground

I love a good "fancy complex" type utility.

The inversion of string extends K is clever.

To restrict keyof to only the defined properties of B, you can introduce an interface that explicitly declares those properties. Then, B will implement this interface, ensuring that only the properties in the interface are considered when using keyof.
export abstract class Definition {
    [x: string]: string;
}

interface IB {
    propA: string;
    propB: string;
}

class B extends Definition implements IB {
    propA = 'A';
    propB = 'B';
}

// Now keyof IB only refers to explicitly defined properties of B (propA, propB)
type BClassKey = keyof IB;

const keyOfBClass: BClassKey = 'propA'; // Valid
const invalidKeyOfBClass: BClassKey = 'thisIsNotValidKey'; // Error: Type '"thisIsNotValidKey"' is not assignable to type 'keyof IB'

Moreover, the code is clean and readable, without the need for complex TypeScript utility types or exclusions.

Sounds like an option. How about mentioned "fancy complex Typescript utility types"? The idea is that having export type KeyOfClass and passing class definition would be more convenient that defining interfaces for each of the class (and yes, current codebase has many of classes already defined with complex property types (string types were only for simplicity), so redefining interfaces for all of those classes would be pain) instead of defining one complex utility class if it is possible.
